# Filter the Grand Total of a Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I am tracking a daily compliance percentage for activities.  I want to trend the monthly average compliance for the 10 tests with the lowest compliance total.  I am having issues trying to figure out the best way to do this since I am unable to filter by the grand total.  Attached is a picture of what the pivot table looks like.

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes, this is how pivot tables in Excel works. If you need to filter for them, then you need to calculate it in a new column in your source data, then use this new column as a row label in the pivot table.

Comment: Each test is a column in the data table.  Two times a day (AM and PM Shift) I update 5 lines of compliance percentages (one for each production line). There are currently 100 columns on the data worksheet.  If I add another column for each test, then this workbook will be VERY massive.  I am looking for ideas on how to do this without adding more columns to that table.

Comment: If you could post a few sample data, that would help to understand your problem.

Comment: I ended up creating a new table (beside the pivot) that is indexed by cell so even if the order of the pivot changes, the top 20 rows will be what is copied over.  Then I created the chart from the new table.  Thanks for helping!

Comment: could you please post your solution as an answer? That would help also others to learn from your case.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I am not sure how to post a 'solution'.  The reply comments will not allow me to add images.  I am not even sure how to mark it as completed.

Comment: You are a button "answer your own question", push that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new table (beside the pivot) that is indexed by cell so even if the order of the pivot changes, the top 20 rows will be what is copied over. Then I created the chart from the new table. Thanks for helping!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Value filters' Value Filters command from the menu in the Column Labels field

https://www.accountingweb.com/technology/excel/filtering-grand-total-amounts-within-excel-pivot-tables